# Using Arduino Sensors with STM32 based NUCLEO boards

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, stm32

Right now I'm programming an Arduino Uno Rev3, I'm using a Sensor Shield v5 *(image at the bottom)* to be able to have several Ultrasonic sensors and Servos. Right now I'm thinking about getting a [Nucleo](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards/nucleo-f446re.html) board, due to the better CPU, more memory and more flash. Although on the page, Arduino compatibility is listed, I don't quite understand what it means in my case. I understand that it has the same pins as the Arduino, but can I be sure that my Sensor Shield (v5) will work?

I found too little resources about this, one concern was that Arduino and Nucleo board have separate needs (3V or 5V), but the Sensor Shield can get power separately. (Lower right corner.)

Also, there is a [Bluetooth shield](https://www.st.com/en/ecosystems/x-nucleo-idb05a1.html) for the Nucleo, I will buy it if I buy the Nucleo board, how can I know that it will work with the Sensor Shield? Or how can I know how many shields can I connect to a Nucleo or an Arduino?

[image: Sensor Shield]

Comment: The "sensor shield" is nothing more than a replacement for wires. You really don't need it. It's just lazy.

Comment: buy Arduino Mega if you need more flash and SRAM. what for do you need so much faster CPU? with Mega you will not have problems with 5 V to 3.3 V logic levels.

Comment: the support for STM32F4 in the STM32 Arduino core is very new.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the fast reply.
So with Sensor Shield, I wouldn't have problems with 3.3/5V as I mentioned, because it can use a separate power supply.
I wasn't aware of theat Sensor Shield is lazy, I got it with my Arduino and it helped me a lot, also I think I would need a breadboard for 7 sensor without it, so it stays.
I just don't understand how many shields I can get to Arduino/STM32 because I don't quite understand how I can read values from them if I connect (for example) a Bluetooth Shield and several other shield.